# AES Base64 256 bit Encryption and Decryption with key in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to decrypt the data which is coming from the java server, but I am not able to do achieve that.

At the server end, they have used **AES Base-64 256 bit Encoder and Decoder**

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://maniacdev.com/2011/06/open-source-easy-base-64-encodedecode-and-aes-encryption-library/) is post explains what you want .

Comment: I referred that example ,but when i give encoded string as input (Encoding done   in Java server) it's not decoding properly . Its giving special symbols and characters.

Comment: NSString *password = @"12";     NSString *b64EncStr = @"QAG/1AzeZk+ZsM0aYQ==";        NSData *b64DecData = [Base64 decode:b64EncStr];
 
 NSData *decryptedData = [b64DecData AESDecryptWithPassphrase:password];
 
 NSString* decryptedStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decryptedData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
 
 NSLog(@"decrypted string = %@",decryptedStr);                       Encrypted Str :QAG/1AzeZk+ZsM0aYQ==                   Pass:12                            Its not decoding properly